# (Excercise 11.17 in Baby Rudin) Why the integral $\int_{E} \sin n x dx$ is the imaginary part of the Fourier coefficient?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-measure, fourier-series

**Exercise 11.17 in Baby Rudin(Principles of Mathematical Analysis)**:

Suppose $E\subset (-\pi,\pi), m(E) > 0,\delta > 0$. Use the Bessel inequality to prove that there are at most finitely many integers $n$ such that $\sin nx \ge \delta$ for all $x \in E$.

**A solution I found is as following**:

For any integer with this property we have $\int_{E} \sin n x d x \geq \delta \mu(E)$,
and the Bessel inequality implies that this inequality can hold for only a finite number of $n$. (The integral is the imaginary part of the Fourier coefficient of the $\mathscr{L}^{2}$-function $\chi_{E}$.)

Need help to under why "**the integral is the imaginary part of the Fourier coefficient of the $\mathscr{L}^{2}$-function $\chi_{E}$**". Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, it's "understand" instead of "under".

Comment: Do you know what a Fourier coefficient is?

Comment: Do you know what an indicator function is?

Comment: Do you know Euler's formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, $\int _E\sin (nx)=-Im (\int_Ee^{-inx} I_E(x) dx)$. But the minus sign does not matter for the proof since we can replace $E$ by $-E=\{-x: x \in E\}$.